# Convert an associative array to a simple of its values in php

Tags: php

I would like to convert the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [send_to] => 9891616884
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [send_to] => 9891616884
        )

)
```

to

```
$value = 9891616884, 9891616884
```

Comment: And where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//example array
$array = array(
    array('send_to'=>3243423434),
    array('send_to'=>11111111)
);

$value = implode(', ',array_column($array, 'send_to'));

echo $value; //prints "3243423434, 11111111"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_map:

```
$input = array(
  array(
    'send_to' => '9891616884'
  ),
  array(
    'send_to' => '9891616884'
  )
);

echo implode(', ', array_map(function ($entry) {
  return $entry['tag_name'];
}, $input));
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple, try this:

```
// initialize and empty string    
$str = '';  

// Loop through each array index
foreach ($array as $arr) {
   $str .= $arr["send_to"] . ", ";
}

//removes the final comma and whitespace
$str = trim($str, ", ");
```